# Kubernetes nodeSelector doesn't remove pods when the node label is gone

Tags: kubernetes

I have a statefulset which has a nodeSelector:

```
  nodeSelector:
    app: licensed
```

When I assign the node with `app: licensed`, I can see the pod is schedule on a specific node.

But when I remove the label from the node, I don't see k8s remove the pod from that node. I have to explicitly delete the pod.

Is it a kubernetes feature? Or did I use the nodeSelector correctly?

Comment: Yes, it only works for scheduling... this is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is likely [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions) if you want only designated things to run on designated Nodes. The `nodeSelector:` you used is used in the scheduling decision, but is not used in the reconciliation loop *(as you experienced)*

There is more fine grained control via the `effect: NoSchedule`, which as it implies will keep a Pod merely from being scheduled if it doesn't tolerate the taint, and `effect: NoExecute` which is closer to what you're asking for where if a taint *appears* on a Node, and the Pod doesn't tolerate it, the Pod will be evicted and not rescheduled upon any such tainted Node. Modern versions of kubernetes allow even finer grained control via the `PreferNoSchedule` and the opposite end of that with `tolerationSeconds` to give some padding around how soon any such eviction may happen